# Vertex AI pipelines TypeError: PipelineTask.add_node_selector_constraint() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given

Tags: python, google-cloud-vertex-ai, large-language-model, vertex-ai-pipeline, kfp

I am trying to have set a the NVIDIA_L4 GPU on my custom Vertex AI pipeline but running into the following issue: Vertex AI pipelines TypeError: PipelineTask.add_node_selector_constraint() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given
What should I do to resolve this?

I tried doing the following:

```
@pipeline(name = 'llm-pipeline')
def data_pipeline():

    answer =  answer_prompt()
    answer.add_node_selector_constraint('cloud.google.com/gke-accelerator', 'NVIDIA_L4')
```

But it didn't work.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to call this method is to pass one argument explicitly like so: `answer.add_node_selector_constraint('NVIDIA_L4')`

See docs [here](https://kubeflow-pipelines.readthedocs.io/en/latest/source/dsl.html?h=node_selector_const#kfp.dsl.PipelineTask.add_node_selector_constraint). Check out other versions as necessary (the link is for latest version)

Note though that this seems to be a recent change, I have seen docs for KFP 1.8.13 that say to use a format more like what you used there (though I haven't tried that personally so not sure how exactly that would work).